# Has anyone compiled FreeBSD with LTO-capable linker?

Tags: unix, kernel, llvm, freebsd, llvm-clang

Has anyone enabled the libLTO when compiling the FreeBSD kernel(in order to compute a whole-program call graph). I want to compile the FreeBSD kernel using the libTO tool from the llvm/clang compiler suite. If anyone has previously done this work then can anyone show me how it is done or how to proceed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Wiki page called [Building FreeBSD with Clang](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BuildingFreeBSDWithClang#Link_Time_Optimizations) has a section regarding this. According to it, it's possible to perform LTO on kernel and get bootable binary. The page itself is somewhat old though, for example you don't need `setenv CC clang` step anymore, so your mileage may wary.

Comment: I did see that page but I am not able to build the libLLVMgold.so. Also this page is somewhat ambiguous as the steps defined in that tutorial were perfomed on i386 only.

Comment: also there are very few available resources on the internet on running things on FreeBSD.

Comment: If you want to get help, post exact errors that prevent you from building.